# For $n\ge \space 2$ , is a fixed positive integer and $f(x)=x^n\mid x \mid, \space x \space \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: derivatives

Options given are:

A. $f$ is differentiable everywhere only when $n$ is even.

B. $f$ is differentiable everywhere except at $0$ if  $n$  is odd

C.$f$ is differentiable everywhere

D.None of the above.

I cannot understand what has n being even or odd to do anything with $f$ being differentiable?

Please help.

Comment: What is $f(x)=x^n\mid x\mid$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $x^n \times \mid x\mid= f(x)$ This was the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $x|x|=x^2$. Second, $x^2|x|=|x^3|$.

So we see that, if $n$ is odd then $x^n|x|=x^{n+1}$ and $n+1$ is even, that is, $x^{n+1}$ is differentiable everywhere.

If, however, $n$ is even the $x^n|x|=|x^{n+1}$|. That is, the question is: if $m$ is odd then is $|x^m|$  differentiable?

Now, $x^m$ is differentiable from the right, no question about that. The derivative is zero at zero. Also, $-x^m$ is differentiable from the left, and the derivative is zero at zero again.

So, $|x^m|$ is differentiable for all $x$ and for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let note

- $x\ge 0 \implies f(x)=x^{n+1}\implies f'(x)=(n+1)x^n$
- $x< 0 \implies f(x)=-x^{n+1}\implies f'(x)=-(n+1)x^n$

and by definition of derivative at $x=0$

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|h^{n}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} (\operatorname{sign}(h)\cdot h^{n-1})=0$$

and then $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Thats exactly what I have done. But just plot the graph it appears to me it is differentiable everywhere. (ofcourse by looking at the plot and intuition)

Comment: @Saradamani Let apply the definition of derivative at $x=0$ $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: I did all the steps you did @gimusi but then suddenly I remembered a question $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is continuous but not differentiable at x=0. I still have doubts with that solution which is why I drew the graph and my intention was to see whether one can draw a tangent at x=0 or not.And it is possible for any $n \ge 2$ Thats why I conclude with option C-differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @Saradamani here we have an expression for derivatives for $x\neq 0$ and by the definition we obtain that $f'(0)=0$, therefore f(x) is differentiable everywhere. The case of $\sin \frac1x$ is completely different.

Comment: Ok I understand your point. I agree. Thanks.

Comment: @Saradamani You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Saradamani I've just fixed a typo in the last step!